# Input text bug on Firefox but not Safari or Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

For some reason my contact form, which worked previously, is not functioning properly all of a sudden. Essentially, the input fields appear to be disabled on Firefox, even though they aren't. Firebug suggests they aren't disabled as well and this behavior only pertains to firefox, not chrome or safari.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid contact-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 footer-contact-h">TELL US ABOUT YOUR PROJECT</div>
            <form method="post" id="contact-form">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-2 col-md-4 col-lg-4 form-row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" required="required" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 form-row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="company" type="text" class="form-control" id="company" placeholder="Company" required="required" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-2 col-md-4 col-lg-4 form-row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 form-row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="phone" type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" required="required" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="message" required="required" placeholder="Details"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control contact-us-button" type="submit" value="CONTACT US">
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact-status">Message Received!</div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was able to replicate it in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tfdcgjh1/

Comment: Looks the same to me in Chrome and FF: http://www.bootply.com/0iKPO8LDmu

Comment: I am using a Mac and the example as shown in JSFiddle which is identical to my live site, is all messed up (no placeholders, inability to input text, etc) on Firefox but not in chrome or safari.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but I presume you don't have source-control that allow you to see what you've changed?

Comment: I used jsfiddle regarded in the question with FireFox 37.0.1 -windows7 64 bit- and I found this bug too.

Comment: @freefaller, nothing had changed as far as my code between the time it was working and now, which is why I presume this is a bug and perhaps not code related.

Comment: Playing with your jsfiddle, removing the `padding:20px 20px;` from `.form-group input` appears to make it come back.  No, I have no idea either

Comment: Ah, change it to `padding:15px` and you can see that it partially hides the textbox contents!

Comment: What the crap why would it do that?! I should be able to have a padding of 1000px and it should still work... Anyways, nice catch, I appreciate the help :) BTW, this is probably linked to the new release of Firefox, because as I stated, it did work until recently.

Comment: According to this, I'm not sure it's FF... http://stackoverflow.com/a/24449464/930393

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it, work around, by doing the following in `form-control` class:

```
.form-control {
    line-height: 1;
    height: auto;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Checkout the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tfdcgjh1/3/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be the `padding` in your `.form-group input`.

Remove that and the placeholder/text comes back.

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfdcgjh1/4/)