# Why does Safari & Firefox cut off bottom of input text?

Tags: html, css, firefox, safari

### What I want

*Chrome*
[image]
On Chrome, the input text looks normal.

### What is happening

*Firefox*
[image]

*Safari*
[image]

As you can see, the input text is being slightly cut off at the bottom on Firefox and majorly cut off on Safari. How can I fix that?

If anyone could help w/ this it would be greatly appreciated!

### Code

*HTML*

```
        <div class="row page-header">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="Worksheet-Name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Worksheet Name..." aria-label="Write worksheet name here"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

*CSS*

```
/*Add borders when hover or click on input boxes*/
input[type="text"] {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow:none !important;
    border: 1px solid white; /*make the borders invisble by turning same color as background*/
}

input[type="text"]:hover, input[type="text"]:focus{
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

/*Style input text boxes*/
input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Name']{
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Problem']{
    font-size: 20px;
}

/*Change placeholder*/
input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Name']::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
    font-weight: 500; 
    font-size: 36px;
}
input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Name']::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 36px;
}
input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Name']:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 36px;
}
input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Name']:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 36px;
}

/*Change placeholder*/
input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Problem']::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
    font-weight: 400; 
    font-size: 20px;
}
input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Problem']::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
}
input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Problem']:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
}
input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Problem']:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/faxnwoah/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reduce the bottom padding and/or the font size and that will fix your overflow issue.

```
input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Name']{
    font-size: 35px;//instead of 36
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

or

```
.input-lg {
    height: 46px;
    padding: 10px 16px 0;//change here to have 0
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.33333;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

also possibly answered here with line-height:
[Why is Firefox cutting off the text in my <input type="text"/>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900018/why-is-firefox-cutting-off-the-text-in-my-input-type-text)

Answer (score 11):

Guys sometimes proposed solutions don't work with placeholders, here is more powerful approach:

```
input::placeholder {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Fixed this with `line-height:1` on the `input`

Answer (score 4):

The cause is placing the line-height on the placeholder, if you remove that then it will no longer be cut

Comment: that worked for me. Had to give it line-height:160%; thanks!!